# Can QGIS Time Manager be used with millions of data points?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have several months of tracking data for researchers driving across north america and i would like to animate their progress.  The Time Manager seems to work fine for maybe one weeks worth of one researchers data but if I use a much larger data set it freezes Qgis.  Is there a way to run the plugin through something other than QGis desktop like a command prompt so I can monitor progress and spot any data errors?

Maybe an alternative that can handle several million data points?

Comment: To speed things up, put the data into a PostGIS database and an index on the timestamp.

Comment: I don't have one set up nor have I ever set one up.  How much faster is the processing?

Comment: Considerably. Relative speedup depends on datasource you're using now. SpatiaLite with index could be an alternative if you cannot install PostGIS.

Comment: Done and done.  It certainly sped it up, however there doesn't seem to be any way of pointing Time Manager to the index on the timestamp. Is there a particular index name I should use?

Comment: I wondered the same thing @underdark . By default in the Time manager settings in the Index field a variable is defined. But this is not the name of the index I created on the timestamp. And I think you should post your comment as a answer for it looks to be the correct one to me.

Answer (score 2):

Put the data into a PostGIS database.

An index on the timestamp will speed up rendering considerably.  Relative speedup depends on the datasource you're using now.

SpatiaLite with index could be an alternative if you cannot install PostGIS.